# Rails Assets Precompile in production mode error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run rake assets:prcompile RAILS_ENV=production, I am getting below error.But if i run in development mode it runs fine.

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production

rake aborted!

Uglifier::Error: fs redeclared
```

Environment

**Rails 5.0.7
Ruby 2.4.1**

Could someone helps to resolve this one

Comment: `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Comment: @DeepakMahakale same issue. I think problem is with my javascripts.. if I move javascripts from assets folder and do the precompile . it's working fine

Answer (score 2):

Got the issue.In my application.js file have below codes

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

As per functionality of **require_tree**, it will include current path's all js files recursively. Refer the link https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives

```
In JavaScript files, Sprockets directives begin with //=. In the above case, the file is using the require and the require_tree directives. The require directive is used to tell Sprockets the files you wish to require. Here, you are requiring the files rails-ujs.js and turbolinks.js that are available somewhere in the search path for Sprockets. You need not supply the extensions explicitly. Sprockets assumes you are requiring a .js file when done from within a .js file.

The require_tree directive tells Sprockets to recursively include all JavaScript files in the specified directory into the output. These paths must be specified relative to the manifest file. You can also use the require_directory directive which includes all JavaScript files only in the directory specified, without recursion.
```

In my application , Gruntfile.js  file was declared in two js folders.So, when I was doing the precompile,as the file was declared in two js , it throws error when it tried to compress that file